# Change image on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and I would like to change an image in its `<td>` when I click it but it must be URL of image that I determine before.

That URL of image I type to the link of the page(for example by click on img)

```
index.html?type=dog
```

Then  the script will read variables from link. I will create variable to the script.

```
type = httpGetVars["type"]
```

Now when I click on  where is img of cat, the script should replace **cat**.png for **dog**.png and I tried it in this way.

```
<img src="cat.png" onClick="document.write("<img src=\""+ type + ".png\">);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img id="foo" src="cat.png />
```

Give that `<img>` an id - `foo` for example than:

```
document.getElementById('foo').src = type +".png";
```

You simply change the existing `<img>` src to the new image.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `img` like the following:

```
<img src="some_image_url.extension" onclick="switchImage(this)" />​
```

and then on the `switchImage` function you can check the current image and change to a different image:

```
var switchImage = function(image) {
    if(image.src == dogImage) {
        image.src = catImage;
    } else {
        image.src = dogImage;
    }
};​
```

I've made a [**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/zBJjB/) so you can see it running.

Comment: Hey, thanks men :) you helped me... I will try both examples :)